# to compare data of above 2 lists & add unique items only to 3rd list

Tags: python, list-comprehension, unique

I tried to get it this way, but it didn't work:

```
item1 = ['eraser', 'pen', 'pencil', 'ruler']
item2 = ['marker', 'pen', 'sharpner', 'compass', 'eraser']

unique_item = [item for item in item1 if item in item2]

print("Unique items from the list", unique_item)
```

Comment: Could you please tell us a little more? What result do you get, and why is it different than what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `set` and subtract the intersection from the union:

```
>>> set_1 = set(['eraser','pen','pencil','ruler'])
>>> set_2 = set(['marker','pen','sharpner','compass','eraser'])
>>> list((set_1 | set_2) - (set_1 & set_2))
['compass', 'marker', 'sharpner', 'ruler', 'pencil']
```

Or use method `set.symmetric_difference()`:

```
>>> list(set_1.symmetric_difference(set_2))
['compass', 'ruler', 'pencil', 'marker', 'sharpner']
```

Comment: But I want to comprehensions method

Comment: @AbhishekAjatdesai Can you tell me the reason why you have to use list comprehension? In this way, you need to chain two list comprehensions, which is not readable and wastes performance.